# computing De Rham cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

Compute $H^{\ast}_{DR}\left(R^{2}-P-Q\right)$ where P and Q are two points in $R^{2}$.Find the closed forms that represent the cohomology group classes.

All the exact zero forms are constant functions. So $H^{0}\left(R^{2}-P-Q\right)$=$R$. Since there are two holes in the plane, we can't use Green theorem to compute cohomology groups as we do when we consider the whole plane. Should we use some new method to solve this problem.

Comment: Probably you mean "all closed forms are constant", not "all exact forms"..

Comment: Did you learn about the Mayer-Vietoris sequence? Try using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each hole has a corresponding closed non exact winding number, or angle form (dTheta, but centered at the point), so this gives 2 independent de Rham cocycles.  then given any closed loop in the plane missing those 2 points, extend to a map of the disc that has those two points as regular values.  removing two small discs, one centered at each hole, shows by green's theorem that the integral of any closed form around the original loop equals the integrals around the boundaries of those two (multiply parametrized) small discs, whence the form differs from a linear combination of the two angle or winding number forms, by an exact form.  thus you have computed the de Rham cohomology group as the span of those 2 independent guys.  so this is almost just elementary calculus of two variables.

Comment: There are some technical details I don't understand.Can you specify what is closed non exact winding number form?What does "extend to a map of the disc that has those two points as regular values." means?Really appreciate your help.

Comment: it is trivial to extend to a map of the disc, since the plane is convex.  to get that we can make two given points regular values, we should be able to ( I never did) generalize the argument in Milnor's differential top[ology notes, that you can make any one point a regular valuie.  a regular value is a value where the differential is surjective.

Comment: the winding number form about the origin is dTheta = -dy/(x^2+y^2) + dx/(x^2+y^2) = darctan(y/x).  just translate this to the given point.

Comment: see  maybe thm 1.21 http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/difftop.pdf